# Upgrading Existing Store from Magento Enterprise edition version 1.12 to version 1.14

Tags: magento-enterprise, upgrade, ee-1.12, enterprise-1.14

We have a Magento Web Store build with **Magento Enterprise Edition** version 1.12. We are planning to upgrade it to version 1.14. We understand that we will need to do an incremental upgrade i.e. from 1.12 to 1.13 first and then from 1.13 to 1.14. I have a few questions regarding this as below:

1. Is the plan correct about doing **incremental upgrade** rather than direct to 1.14?
2. We are planning to do the upgrade via Magento Connect rather than manual or through ssh, should that be ok?
3. Our store has around 81 **extensions including paid/free**, some of them we developed, so does this mean it would be more difficult. Note: only a few are customized and most of them are not and compatibility checks already done.
4. If we go for incremental upgrade, does it mean, we have to pay for version 1.13 too?
5. We have identified following steps, does it make sense or any other/better way to do this?

Backup of complete site and DB and create a new instance where upgrade will happen.

list all extensions and details about them like paid/free, customized/not, licenses etc.

Do the following steps on the new instance created for upgradation.

- Enable exceptions logging in the system
- Flush Magento Cache & disable it.
- Making sure all crons are disabled.
- Make sure built-in compiler is disabled if enabled
- Modifying indexers settings to update when scheduled rather than automatic
  Complete the Upgrade as per Magento Steps using Magento connect.
- Deprecation errors may come due to PHP pugradation which needs to be handled
- Delete file named maintenance.flag from root
- Changing URLs based on changes to 1.13 using URL redirect scripts.

> [Magento install dir]/php -f shell/url_migration_to_1_13.php -
>   thread-count. thread-count is the number of CPU cores in Magento
>   server, minus 1, to a maximum of 15

- Full re-indexing from command line.

> [Magento install dir]/php -f shell/indexer.php — –reindexall

- Make sure to check if all URLs work in this instance
- clear `[Magento install dir]/var/cache` `/var/full_page_cache` `/var/locks`
  enable crons, enable cache, modify indexer settings and make it default (update when scheduled) and delete the /var directory.
- If built-in compiler was disabled then re-enable it
- Review all extensions one by one and compare functionalities related to each extensions with Live instance and make sure they work as they should on upgraded version
- Making sure all custom code is applied to the upgraded version
- Verify complete web store functionalities are working

I would appreciate some insight on this. Are we missing anything here?

Answer (score 3):

First: You will not be able to do this by Magento Connect, nor would I ever recommend using Magento connect [for anything]. The EE code is not available on connect so it will be impossible for you to do this.

According to Magento You **DO NOT** have to do an incremental upgrade, but you will have to run your URL migration scripts.

You will need to test and apply the new XML updates on your theme.

There is alot of work involved in this upgrade and there are many steps that have to happen and you need to check each aspect of the upgrade. I would recommend having your Magento Solution Integrator handle your upgrade.

**Read the WIKI on upgrades**
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/manual_upgrade_using_fresh_install_and_original_database

**Read the important bit on upgrading from Magento Enterprise 1.12**
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_landing.html#ee1300-11301-upgrade-to-ee11302-start

Comment: Hi @brentwpeterson,

Thanks for taking time to go through my question and all points i mentioned. Just wanted to let you know about a few things:

1. We would be redesigning the complete theme anyways after the upgrade, so "Apply the new XML updates to theme" is required?
2. I have read a lot in almost all places about it is possible through Magento Connect, not sure how?
3. Not sure what you mean by having Magento Solution integrator handling the upgrade.

Please forgive me in case any of the above sounds dumb to you :)

Have not used EE a lot so not sure about most of the things.

Thanks,
C

Comment: If you are redesigning your theme then you can use the built in RWD theme. - You are using EE so there is no option for EE.

Comment: You mean to say not copying theme files from my existing store?Now, for upgrade you mean to say setting up a new source code for EE 1.14 somewhere and copying files over from old web store to this instance except the theme files, since we will use default RWD theme as per you. Is this the method you are suggesting? Would i need to purchase license for 1.14 EE or would having a license of 1.12 suffice. Sorry again for a lot of questions. As you know the size and complexity of the website is big, i want to absolutely be sure before choosing a way to do it to reduce rework. Thanks in advance, C

Comment: You would not copy any theme files. You will need to renew your subscription to EE (If it is expired)